# Symfony Doctrine ManyToOne association migration No reaction

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, migration

I have two tables one is entry.php and user.php

I Want to associate $balance of user with the $balance of entry

but when I try **php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff**

I get

> No changes detected in your mapping information.

this is my user.php

```
<?php
namespace BankBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="BankBundle\Entity\user")
 **/
class user
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id",type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="entry", mappedBy="balance")
     * @var entry[] An ArrayCollection of entry objects.
     */
    private $balance;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    public function getBalance()
    {
        return $this->balance;
    }
}
```

and my entry.php

```
<?php
namespace BankBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="entry")
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="BankBundle\Repository\BankRepository")
 **/
class entry
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id",type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="amount",type="integer")
     */
    private $amount;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="balance",type="integer")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="user", inversedBy="balance")
     */
    private $balance;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at",type="datetime")
     */
    private $created_at;
}
```

Comment: What is the output of `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql`?

Comment: @xabbuh is Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.

Comment: When I INSERT something into entry.php that $balance of user is not change with  $blance of entry

Comment: Can you clarify the actual changes you applied to your entity mapping config after updating the database schema the last time?

Comment: @xabbuh just add @ORM\ManyToOne in entry.php and @ORM\OneToMany in user.php

Comment: don't use `@ORM\Column` with `@ORM\ManyToOne`, you can use `@ORM\JoinColumn` with `@ORM\ManyToOne` though (and it will automatically use the correct type for the column)

Comment: Entry table contains user_id field? If so, thats why it does not apply changes...